# Error with Firebase on flutter for iOs pods

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I try to launch my app on my iOS simulator. But I've got this problem ...

I've tried many things but it's still now working. This is the error:

```
      Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           492,4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTTransactionStreamHandler.m:6:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/macbookair/Developer/testFirebase2/testfirebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
    /Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/macbookair/Developer/testFirebase2/testfirebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTTransactionStreamHandler.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Did you try to do ```flutter clean``` and rebuild ?

Comment: Yes but till doesn't work ...

Comment: Can you give us a idea of what you already tested ?

Comment: I ve seen that could be great to put my platform on 10.0 , 
 platform :ios, '10.0' on my iOS/Podfile 
I think the problem can be on my podfile ? 
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

Comment: Yes you can try to put the platform to 10.0 or try ***delete podfile and podfile.lock***

Comment: I've done both but still not working ...